# Javascript onClick wont execute unless clicked twice

Tags: javascript, html

having another problem with my javascript for my table. Basically, if you look at the link I post, I have three cells with checkmarks and coloured red. When I click on the cell, the checkmark is removed and the cell changes colour. I want to make my reset button return the table to its initial state. However, this takes two clicks. You can test this out on the link here: http://cs1.ucc.ie/~od1/project_css/

Viewing the source there would be best but here is my javascript code that won't allow it to work:

```
        function resetColour(objName){
            var arr = document.getElementsByName(objName);
            var arrLen = arr.length;

            for(var i = 0; i < arrLen; i++){
                if(arr[i].checked){
                    arr[i].parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "#F26C4F";
                }
                else{
                    arr[i].parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "#FAF4E3";
                }
            } 
        }
```

Is there any way I can make the form both reset and change colour with ONE click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because it calls the function before the actual reset happen. The simplest (but the worst) way you can do is to wait for a few milliseconds to call your function.

```
<input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" onclick="setTimeout('resetColour(\'free\')',200)" class="button">
```

**Edit**
Better option is to use normal button instead of reset button and call the function first and then the form.reset

```
<input type="button" value="Reset Form" onClick="resetColour('free')';this.form.reset()" />
```

Comment: Thanks a million. I had actually used setTimeout to try and solve the program but I just messed up the timings, didn't give my machine enough credit!

Comment: Your second solution was another thing I tried but didn't work. The top one works perfectly, I have even gotten the time down to 5ms

Comment: I would be weary of the `setTimeout` solution.  Though, unlikely: it is conceivable that the reset on sufficiently large enough forms and slow enough computers will not happen at the time your function is set to execute.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `onclick` event handler is fired *before* the action the browser performs is executed (so you can `return false` and cancel the event; usually useful. There is no `onafterclick` event, but there's an alternative.

Rather than have the logic to alter the color of the table cells reside with the reset button, put it on the checkboxes, themselves, with the `onchange` event.

You can register them programmatically with a `for` loop and that callback is called *after* a value is changed, instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how i would do it.

Use a regular button

```
<input type="button" value="Reset Form" onClick="resetColour('free')" />
```

Then

```
 function resetColour(objName){
        var arr = document.getElementsByName(objName);
        var arrLen = arr.length;

        for(var i = 0; i < arrLen; i++){
            var checkbox = arr[i]; 
            if( checkbox.hasAttribute('checked') ){
                checkbox.checked = true; 
                checkbox.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "#F26C4F";
            }
            else{
                checkbox.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "#FAF4E3";
            }
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that putting a `setTimeout` or `return false` on an `onclick` is the wrong way to go about this.

I would, instead, use the `onreset` event of the `form`.

A very simple example would look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>sfs</title>

<style type="text/css">

form {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    border: solid black 1px;    
}


</style>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function hello( form ) {
    form.style.backgroundColor = "#F26C4F";         
}


</script>

</head>

<body>

<form onreset="hello(this)">

<input type="input" value="blah" />

<input type="reset" value="Reset" />

</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Though, a slightly more advanced subject.  I would improve it by making the function you hook to the `onreset` event no longer inline:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>sfs</title>

<style type="text/css">

form {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    border: solid black 1px;    
}


</style>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function() {
    document.forms["myForm"].onreset = function() {
        this.style.backgroundColor = "#F26C4F";         
    }
}

</script>

</head>

<body>

<form name="myForm">

<input type="input" value="blah" />

<input type="reset" value="Reset" />

</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Also, it is worth noting, that when the `onreset` event is fired, you have the state of the form just prior to the fields being reset to their default.  So it should be a non-issue if you need to do something with an existing value prior to reset.

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest you use jQuery and perform an artificial click, like so :

```
$('#formSubmitButtonIDHere').trigger('click');
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you're suggesting to load a massive library for a page that doesn't really use it just to perform a nasty hack that doesn't actually solve the issue (the fact that the event is being fired before the checkbox values are changed). Also, without being careful, you could easily enter a loop of infinite clicks.

Comment: The poster is not using jQuery. Also you are not fixing the problem just rigging it so it seems to be working correctly.

Comment: I didn't downvote and I appreciate your suggestion. However I don't want to use jquery which is why I didn't tag it.

Comment: Yeah, some folk down vote in an attempt to discredit other answers to give their answer more weight. I'm trying to help but this practice is annoying and SO should do something about it.